# Can a Geopackage file be created by Spatialite

Tags: spatialite, geopackage

Starting with the Spatialite application, can a new Geopackage file be created, or is Spatialite only capable of working with existing Geopackage files?

Comment: Do you mean the spatialite-gui application or the command line tool? With spatialite-gui you can only create SpatiaLite databases but with the command line utility it should be bossible to creata also GeoPackages.

Comment: I'm more interested in the CLI, but it would be useful to note if it isn't possible via the GUI for example

Comment: There seems to be something about how to do it with CLI tool in thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spatialite-users/rBKeuXLpQv8/2yGdQIIXOUoJ or perhaps they used SQLite plus mod_spatialite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @user30184 and ultimately Sandro Furieri in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spatialite-users/rBKeuXLpQv8/2yGdQIIXOUoJ):

> Creating a crystal-clear GPKG not containing any spatialite specific
>   table is really simple.
>
> You simply have to avoid using either spatialite CLI or spatialite GUI
>   because both tools will always create a new DB-file specifically
>   inteded for SpatiaLite. Anyway a third option exists, and is
>   straighforward.
>
> A) edit the SQL scriptd prepare by Jukka
>       add the following statement before the very first line:
>       SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
>
> B) now you simply have to execute from the shell:
>       sqlite3 test.gpkg
>
> this way you'll get an absolutely clean GPKG

So the answer in the strictest sense is no.

**EDIT 1:**

In place of the script mentioned in the quote above, there is a Spatialite function `gpkgCreateBaseTables` that appears to initialise the requisite Geopackage metadata tables.

**EDIT 2:**

The following commands generate a clean GPKG (using SQLite 3.17.0 and mod_spatialite.dll 4.3.0):

```
C:\>sqlite3.exe SL3_Test.gpkg
sqlite>SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
sqlite>SELECT gpkgCreateBaseTables();
sqlite>.exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new GeoPackage with Spatialite. All you need to do is make sure you create the required MetaData tables (and triggers to populate them).

There must be a [`gpkg_contents`](http://www.geopackage.org/spec/#_contents) table and a [`gpkg_spatial_ref_sys`](http://www.geopackage.org/spec/#spatial_ref_sys). You also need to set the `application_id` to `GPKG`.

However in most cases it will be easier to use a library or tool designed to do it, one is [available](https://www.geopackage.org/implementations.html) in most languages.

Comment: This approach would work, but will generate a sqlite DB that contains both spatialite and geopackage default tables that might cause problems with some applications. I guess the spatialite tables could then be dropped, but Sandro's approach is much cleaner.